# Infix to Postfix and unary/binary operators

Tags: c#, math, rpn

I have a piece of code that converts an infix expression to an expression tree in memory. This works just fine. There's just one small trouble. I just connect work out how to involve the unary operators correctly (the right associative ones).

With the following infix expression :

```
+1 + +2 - -3 - -4
```

I would expect an RPN of:

```
1+2++3-4--
```

Yet, none of the online infix-post converters I can find handle this example in the way I would expect. Does anyone have a clear explanation of handling right associative operators, specifically the binary ones that can be mistaken for the unary ones?

Edit/Clarification:
I would like to know how to deal with the unary operators during the translation from infix to postfix. Ie: recognizing the same '-' character for example as being unary instead of binary operator and thus a different precedence. I would think of using a state machine perhaps with two states but ...?

Comment: @Jaapjan: It is unclear what your problem is. Is it parsing the infix expression? Is it converting the expression tree to RPN?

Comment: You miss a minus sign, it should be `1+2++3--4--`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you need to determine if a given operator is binary/unary during the *parsing* stage. Once you do that, when you create the RPN, you can tag the operators as taking 2 or 1 arguments.

You could try using the [Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) algorithm to do the parsing (and creation of RPN at the same time), which was designed to work with unary operators too.

In any case, if all you care about is unary + or -, you could just insert a 0 with brackets when you see a + or - that appears 'unexpectedly'.

For instance

`+1 + +2 - -3 - -4`

You should be able to make a pass through it and convert to

`(0+1) + (0+2) - (0-3) - (0-4)`

Now you don't need to worry about the unary + or - and can probably forget about tagging the operators with the number of arguments they take.

Comment: Yes, I had implemented the shunting yard algoritm but it, as you say, requires that you have already identified the - and the + as either unary +, - or the binary variations. I ended up using some changed parsing code to beter decide what I am dealing with. I do not want to change the actual expression because I need to write back the parsed expression again. Still, I have some troubles deciding when to write back unary operators to the RPN output. I'll have another look at the algorythm.

Comment: @Jaapjan. RPN evaluation needs to know how many arguments an operator takes. The proper way to do this would be with a grammar which can tell when + is unary and when it is binary etc. btw, why does it matter if you include zeroes in the written back expression? Since you have it tagged as self-learning, it seems like that should be irrelevant.

Comment: It is self-learning because I am trying to learn how to read expressions in my source code using a program. If my program writes back 'cleaned' expressions then I prefer not to have extra zero's in them. Unfortunately it also needs to deal with variable number of parameters to functions. Hence trying to figure out how others deal with this situation. I presume for example -1--1 would become 1 neg 1 neg minus in this instance. But I do not find any clear way to deal with nested expressions with variable length functions in them... mmm.

Comment: @Jaapjan: The wiki for the shunting yard algo has a link to the original paper by Dijkstra which apparently also deals with functions and parameters. Of course, you could do this using standard parsing techniques. Have you heard of the 'dragon' book? Recursive Descent Parsing might be a good option for learning about parsing.

Comment: I accepted your answer. And yes, it does deal with parameters but only when the amount of parameters is known beforehand. I had a prototype earlier that used recursive decent parsing instead of the shunting yard but SY proved, then at least, easier to work with. I have some thoughts still and will pursue the dragon book for some external thoughts from other people. I have accepted your answer, thank you for the time spend.

Answer (score -1):

may be this chaotic C# code will help you. a unary operator has the maximum priority in arithmetic operations, so the precedence will be higher for them.
for identifying unary operator I have taken a boolean variable unary which will be set true after each operator token and false after an operand. 
You have to use a different notation for unary plus and minus operator so that you can distinguish between unary and binary operator in PFE. here
'#' and '~' are used to depict the unary plus and unary minus in postfix expression(PFE).

you can handle all cases like 1+-1,1+(-1),1---1,1+--1 by using this approch.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace DSA
{
    class Calculator
    {
        string PFE;
        public Calculator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Intializing Calculator");
        }

        public double Calculate(string expression)
        {
            ConvertToPost(expression);
            return CalculatePOST();
        }

        public void ConvertToPost(string expression)
        {
            expression = "(" + expression + ")";

            var temp = new DSA.Stack<char>();
            string ch = string.Empty;
            bool unary = true;
            char a;
            foreach (var b in expression)
            {
                a = b;
                if (!a.IsOperator()) {
                    ch += a.ToString();
                    unary = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ch!=string.Empty) 
                    PFE += ch+",";
                    ch = string.Empty;
                    if(a!='(' && a!=')')
                    {
                        if (unary == true)
                        {
                            if (a == '-') a = '~'; else if (a == '+') a = '#'; else throw new InvalidOperationException("invalid input string");
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            if (a.Precedence() <= temp.Peek().Precedence())
                            {
                                PFE += temp.Pop().ToString() + ",";
                            }
                          }
                        catch(InvalidOperationException e)
                        {

                        }

                            temp.Push(a);
                            unary = true;
                    }
                    if (a == '(') { temp.Push(a);}
                    if(a==')')
                    {
                       for(char t=temp.Pop();t!='(';t=temp.Pop())
                        {
                            PFE += t.ToString() + ","; 
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        public double CalculatePOST()
        {
            var eval = new Stack<double>();
            string ch = string.Empty;
            bool skip = false;
            foreach(char c in PFE)
            {
                if(!c.IsOperator())
                {
                    if (c == ',')
                    {
                        if (skip == true)

                        {
                            skip = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                        eval.Push(Double.Parse(ch));
                        ch = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else ch += c;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c == '~')
                    {
                        var op1 = eval.Pop();
                        eval.Push(-op1);
                    }
                    else if (c == '#') ;
                    else
                    {
                        var op2 = eval.Pop();
                        var op1 = eval.Pop();
                        eval.Push(Calc(op1, op2, c));
                    }
                    skip = true;
                }
              }
            return eval.Pop();
        }

        private double Calc(double op1, double op2, char c)
        {   
           switch(c)
            {

                case '+':
                    return op1 + op2;
                case '-':
                    return op1 - op2;
                case '*':
                    return op1 * op2;
                case '%':
                    return op1 % op2;
                case '/':
                    return op1 / op2;
                case '^':
                    return float.Parse(Math.Pow(op1,op2).ToString());
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }


    public static class extension
    {
        public static bool IsOperator(this char a)
        {
            char[] op = {'+','-','/','*','(',')','^','!','%','~','#'};
             return op.Contains(a);
        }

        public static int Precedence(this char a)
        {
            if (a == '~' || a== '#')
                return 1;
            if (a == '^')
                return 0;
            if (a == '*' || a == '/' || a=='%')
                return -1;
            if (a == '+' || a == '-')
                return -2;
            return -3;       
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code, so that others can learn from it? Stackoverflow is not about dumping in code that others can just blnidly copy & paste, but about learning and understanding how things work.

Comment: @Robert I am bad at explaining.some edits are made considering your comment, but can you suggest some improvement in above explanation? thanks.