# Postfix to Infix expression conversion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, postfix-notation

Can anyone provide me with any resource relating to Postfix to Infix expression conversion algorithm?

Examples would be much helpful.

Comment: -1 No prior research shown. This is a typical course assignment and there are many examples online.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some relevant looking hits that I obtained by googling "postfix to infix converter":

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/PostfixtoInfixConversion.htm

http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_convert_from_postfix_to_infix_in_Java

[Postfix to infix with unary/binary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438740/postfix-to-infix-with-unary-binary-operators)