# shunting yard algorithm with trigonometric functions

Tags: c#, parsing, mathematical-expressions, shunting-yard

I am working on implementing shunting yard algorithm in C#.  Although it parses mathematical expressions with symbols( + , * - / and ^) pretty well.But for some reason it is not working for sine cosine functions . Like for example if I try to calculate sin(45) I get 0.707106 .
But when I try to parse expression like

---

```
   sin(25)+cos(15+sin(25))+3  it gives me 0.43756   (Correct answer is: 2.19106879911)
```

---

```
    sin(45)+cos(45) it gives me 0.715779      (Correct answer is: 1.414)
```

I have followed all the steps that are mentioned in this article [at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) . I have trying this for a few days now but I am unable to make it work perfectly. Here is the main parsing function

```
    private void parse()
{
    //scan the input string
    for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
    {

        if (Char.IsDigit(input[j])) //if its a number
        {
            string number = extractNumber(input, j);  //extracts multiple digit number
            j = currentposition; //increment the counter according to length of the digit
            postfix += number + " ";
            Console.WriteLine(postfix);
        }
            //if its a function character
        else if(Char.IsLetter(input[j]) )
        {
            //its a letter
            string function = getFunction(j); //get the function name
            operators.Push( function );
            j = currentposition;

        }
        else if(input[j] == ',') //if its a comma
        {
            while(operators.Peek() != "(")
            {
                postfix += input[j] + " ";

            }

        }
        else if (IsAnOperator(input[j])) // if we have got an operator
        {
           if (operators.Count != 0 && IsHigherPrecedence(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0], input[j]))
            {
                while ( ( operators.Count != 0 && IsHigherPrecedence(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0], input[j]) )  )
                { 
                    postfix += operators.Pop() + " "; 

                }
            }

              operators.Push(Char.ToString(input[j]));
        }
        else if (input[j] == '(')
            operators.Push(Char.ToString(input[j]));
        else if (input[j] == ')')
        {
            while (operators.Count != 0 && operators.Peek() != "(")
                postfix += operators.Pop() + " ";
            operators.Pop();
        }


    } // end for loop

        while(operators.Count > 0 )
            postfix +=operators.Pop() + " ";

     //Conversion Logic  (postfix to final answer )

        postfixtokens.AddRange( postfix.Split(' ') ) ;

    for (int j = 0; j < postfixtokens.Count-1; j++)
    {

        if (IsAnOperator(postfixtokens[j][0]) && basket.Count > 1)
        {

            Double second = Double.Parse( basket.Pop() );

            Double first = Double.Parse(basket.Pop() );
            char op = postfixtokens[j][0];
            Double result = ApplyOperation(op,second, first);
         //   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", first, op, second, result);
            basket.Push( result.ToString());
        }
        else if (IsAnOperator(postfixtokens[j][0]) && basket.Count == 1)
        {

            Double second = Double.Parse(basket.Pop());
            Double first = 0.0;
            char op = postfixtokens[j][0];

            Double result = ApplyOperation(op, second, first);

         //   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} = {3}", first, op, second, result);
            basket.Push(result.ToString() );
        }
        else if (Char.IsDigit(postfixtokens[j][0]))
        {
            basket.Push( postfixtokens[j] );
        }
        else if( isAFunction(postfixtokens[j]) )
        {
            //if its a single argument function
            if (AllowedFunctions[postfixtokens[j]] == 1)
            {
                //single arg logic
                if (postfixtokens[j] == "sin")
                {
                    Double result =  Math.Sin( Double.Parse(basket.Pop() )*Math.PI/180.0 );
                    //result = Math.PI / 180;
                    basket.Push(result.ToString());
                }
                else if (postfixtokens[j] == "cos")
                {
                       Double result =  Math.Cos( Double.Parse(basket.Pop() )*Math.PI/180.0 );
                    //result = Math.PI / 180;
                    basket.Push(result.ToString());
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Moreover,
Here is the output of the program:

```
   Input: 3+4*2/(1-5)^5^10
   PostFix: 3 4 2 * 1 5 - 5 10 ^ ^ / +
   Answer: 3


   Input: 2+4
   PostFix: 2 4 +
   Answer: 6

   Input Expression: -5-4
   Input: -5-4
   PostFix: 5 - 4 -
   Answer: -9

   Input: -4+3
   PostFix: 4 - 3 +
   Answer: -1

   Input Expression: 4^(4^4)
   Input: 4^(4^4)
   PostFix: 4 4 4 ^ ^
   Answer: 1.34078079299426E+154

   Input: sin45
   PostFix: 45 sin
   Answer: 0.707106781186547  (correct)
```

//the faulty ones

```
   Input: sin(25)+cos(15+sin(25))+3
   PostFix: 25 15 25 sin + 3 + cos + sin
   Answer: 0.437567038002202

   Input: sin(45)+cos(45)
   PostFix: 45 45 cos + sin
   Answer: 0.71577935734684
```

New Cases:

```
    Input: sin45+cos45
    PostFix: 45 45 cos + sin
    Answer: 0.71577935734684

    Input: 2+sin30
    PostFix: 2 30 sin +
    Answer:2.5

    Input: sin30+2
    PostFix: 30 2 + sin
    Answer: 0.529919264233205
```

Thats all.Can anybody point me what I am doing wrong.

Edit:

Here is the IsHigherPrecedance function and precedance enum
:

```
    public enum Precedance { Plus =1,Minus=1,Multiply=2,Divide=2,Exponent=3,Unary = 4,Parenthesis=5 };
   private bool IsHigherPrecedence(char a, char b)
   {
    Precedance f = getPrecedance(a);
    Precedance s = getPrecedance(b);


    if (f >= s)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
   }
  public Precedance getPrecedance(char a)
{

    if (a == '+')
        return Precedance.Plus;
    else if (a == '-')
        return Precedance.Minus;
    else if (a == '*')
        return Precedance.Multiply;
    else if (a == '/')
        return Precedance.Divide;
    else if (a == '^')
        return Precedance.Exponent;
    else if (Char.IsLetter(a))
        return Precedance.Unary;
    else if (a == '(' || a == ')')
        return Precedance.Parenthesis;
    else
        return Precedance.Plus;
}
```

Now that these trigonometric function are single argument function, are they going to be parsed with some other logic or does this shunting yard algo works with such functions as well as well?

Regards.

Comment: Immediately I see that your working example for `sin` doesn't have parentheses, but your failing ones do. Is that the problem? Alternatively, you may want to debug the simpler case of what happens when you have two operators, only one of which is `sin`, eg with `2 + sin 30` as an input.

Comment: @L.B  I have already converted the angle from degree to radian.

Comment: @AakashM  I have edited the thread. Please check at the bottom of the thread.

Comment: Umm, the correct Postfix for *Sin(45)+Cos(45)* (or *sin45+cos45*) is `45 sin 45 cos +` and ***not*** `45 45 sin + cos` as two of your examples show.  That's the Postfix for the expression: *Cos(45+Sin(45))*.

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593080/how-can-i-modify-my-shunting-yard-algorithm-so-it-accepts-unary-operators, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431863/infix-to-postfix-and-unary-binary-operators

Comment: @RBarryYoung Please tell me does precedance plays role in evaluating these single arg functions? because what I infer from following the description given on wikipedia page is that only "sin" is a function token (not  sin(45) ). If I follow this rule, then I get postfix of sin(45)+cos(45)  as [45 45 cos + sin]

Comment: It seems you are treating "sin" and "cos" like binary operators not unary operators, although I may just be confused.

Comment: @Jodrell  I treat these functions as unary operator

Comment: and as such, unary operators have a higher precendece to everything but parantheses\brackets in my mind.

Comment: but in your postfix `sin` seems to have the lowest precedence. I don't quit fathom how `IsHigherPrecedence` is implemented or see it in your sample.

Comment: @Jodrell Check the thread again plz

Comment: @Jodrell  can you tell me is "sin" a function token or "sin(args)" a function token?

Comment: precedence has no meaning for functions because of the parenthesis "(..)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a copule of problems here, but the primary one is that you are treating functions as operators, though they are not (intrinsic to this is that you call your stack "operators" as though that is the only thing that can be on it, not true).  In particular, this branch:

```
else if (IsAnOperator(input[j])) // if we have got an operator
{
    if (operators.Count != 0 && IsHigherPrecedence(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0], input[j]))
    {
        while ( ( operators.Count != 0 && IsHigherPrecedence(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0], input[j]) )  )
        { 
            postfix += operators.Pop() + " "; 
        }
    }
    operators.Push(Char.ToString(input[j]));
}
```

needs to check to see if what's on the "operators" stack is actually an operator:

```
else if (IsAnOperator(input[j])) // if we have got an operator
{
    while (operators.Count != 0 
        && IsAnOperator(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0])
        && IsHigherPrecedence(operators.Peek().ToCharArray()[0], input[j]))
    {
       postfix += operators.Pop() + " "; 
    }
    operators.Push(Char.ToString(input[j]));
}
```

---

Other issues include the branch that handles commas:

```
else if (input[j] == ',') //if its a comma
{
    while (operators.Peek() != "(")
    {
        // this isnt right, but its not the problem
        postfix += input[j] + " ";
        // should be this:
        postfix += operators.Pop() + " ";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this library: https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NPEG
you could use this grammar to parse your expression.

```
Digit: (?<Digit>[0-9]+('.'[0-9]+)?);
(?<Trig>): 'sin(' Expr ')' / 'cos(' Expr ')';
Value:  Digit / Trig / '(' Expr ')';
(?<Product>): Value ((?<Symbol>'*' / '/') Value)*;
(?<Sum>): Product ((?<Symbol>'+' / '-') Product)*;
(?<Expr>): Sum ;
```

Test it out here:
http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/npeg-language-workbench

`cos(25)+cos(15+sin(25.333))+3`

`((((12/3)+5-2*(81/9))+1))`

nuget:

Install-Package NPEG

to see a sample evaluation of the AST for boolean algebra.